# "They all are fine" vs. "they are all fine"

Tags: meaning, differences, word-order, determiners

The situation is that someone asks me how my family are; I then want to answer that they all are fine.

I want to know whether the sentences "They all are fine." and "They are all fine." have the same meaning.

Is there any difference? To me as a non-native English speaker, "They all are fine." seems better — it should mean that each of my family members is fine whereas "They are all fine." should mean that each of my family members is completely fine. Please correct my understanding if there is anything wrong.

Comment: Your suggestions are both fine. They both mean the same thing.

Comment: I regret voting to close. The evidence is starting to stack up that there's a significant US/UK difference involved here even for OP's exact example. There are certainly other idiomatic peculiarities about the placement of "all" in various constructions.

Comment: The answer, at least as far as the OP is concerned) should be "they are all fine". This is by far the most common usage in the U.S., and the alternative seems to be ungrammatical in the U.K. It is clearly what should be taught to ESL students.

Answer (score 4):

You have got the meanings almost right.

> 'They all are fine.'

**all** my family members are fine.

> 'They are all fine.'

all my family members are **fine**.

The stress in the first instance is on **all** (Is **everyone** fine?), whereas in the second, it's on **fine** (**How** is everyone?).

Comment: I don't recognise this distinction. [When the verb is a form of be, all is placed after it.](http://www.perfectyourenglish.com/usage/all.htm) Placing *"all"* between the subject and verb is simply an unusual stylistic variation - it conveys no special meaning in OP's context.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I think "they are all fine" is the usual way to say this, but if I wanted to stress the word **all**, then I'd be likely to rearrange the words and say "they **all** are fine" (since I don't think **all** can take much stress in the first word order). On the other hand, you can use both expressions without stressing the word **all**, in which case they mean essentially the same thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, et al.: If everyone whose opinion differs from mine would want to down vote, we will need to rewrite our ELU rules. My answer is based on empirical data, not personal opinion. Down voting has a different purpose -- "this answer is not useful", not "I don't recognise this distinction."

Comment: @Peter Shor: My downvote is because placing *"all"* before the noun is a ***very*** uncommon stylistic variation. So much so that I'd guess the form occurs more often through linguistic incompetence than as a deliberate style choice. Since so many visitors here are *not* competent speakers, I think it's at the very least desirable that where one of two "technically valid" alternatives is overwhelmingly the more common, that fact should be spelt out.

Comment: @Kris: I wasn't aware of any "rules" telling me how I can (or even *should*) cast my votes. Not only do I not recognise your distinction in meaning - I don't accept *"They all are fine"* as standard/normal English in the first place, and I posted a link to a site confirming my position on that.

Comment: Kris: It's quite possible that this is another U.K./U.S. distinction in English usage. Certainly, if this is an extremely rare usage in RP, @FumbleFingers is justified in downvoting based on this. Some American dialects certainly use the pronoun "y'all" ("you all"), and that might make "they all" seem to be a more natural phrasing. (Although you shouldn't conclude from this that Americans who use "youse" also use "theyz". Theyz don't.)

Comment: And indeed, [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=They+all+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3) shows that while U.K. usage of "They all are" was only slightly less than American usage in the 1800s, it's dropped to around 1/3 of what it was, while American usage hasn't declined anywhere near as much, so it's now used around twice as often in the U.S.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I should have expected you to dig more out of NGrams than I could! I fiddled with it for a bit, because my intuition told me that although *all* normally comes before the verb, it invariably comes *after* if the verb is "to be" + adjective, or if there's an auxiliary verb involved. But I couldn't get a clear picture of a US/UK divide. But surely even Americans wouldn't readily accept *"My family all have died"*, for example?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I can't speak for all Americans, but *"My family all have died"* sounds wrong to me and *"They all have died"* doesn't.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Interesting. Hopefully the question will get re-opened. If not, I might ask about placement of *all* myself, because it does seem quite subtle. To me, *They all have died* sounds really strange. But I'm quite happy with *They all have cancer* (semantics aside! :) - I think because that doesn't use "have" as an "auxiliary verb". Conversely, I couldn't accept *They have all cancer*. For me that would have to be *They have all **got** cancer*.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5893/discussion-between-peter-shor-and-fumblefingers)

Answer (score 0):

"They are all fine" is the correct usage.

To simplify to three words, I would say "They are fine". In this case 'all' is implied by the fact that only one word is used to describe the state of all my family members.
If you add 'all', it is making explicit that every member of my family is fine, not just most of them - as a result it needs to be directly before "fine", rather than elsewhere in the sentence.